Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_{k}}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}\geq \frac{n}{4}$

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be positive real numbers. Set $x_{n+1}=x_1$ and $x_{n+2}=x_2$. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_{k}}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}\geq \frac{n}{4}.$$

This looks like Shapiro inequality. The difference is that the R.H.S. of the above inequality is $\frac{n}{4}$.
I tried using AM-GM, CS and mathematical induction. The best that I could obtain, using CS was
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_{k}}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}\geq\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nx_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}=\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)^2}{2\sum_{k=1}^nx_{k}}.$$ It suffices to show that
$$\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^nx_{k}}\geq\frac{n}{2}.$$
I attempted to use MI. In the inductive step, I got
$$\begin{align*}
2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt{x_k}\right)^2&=2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)^2+4\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)\sqrt{x_{n+1}}+x_{n+1}\\
&\geq n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+4\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)\sqrt{x_{n+1}}+x_{n+1}\\
&= (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k+4\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)\sqrt{x_{n+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k-nx_{n+1}.\\
\end{align*}$$
All that's left is to show $4\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k}\right)\sqrt{x_{n+1}}\geq\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+nx_{n+1}$. But I don't know how to proceed.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the AoPS threads Nesbitt like sum (which states the source is "Task M$1454$; Delta Journal") and Inequality (which is posted in the "High School Olympiads" section).

@JohnOmielan Nesbitt like sum doesn't actually answer the question. I can't understand the solution in Inequality, specifically how Karamata's inequality was used. It was also claimed to be wrong by another user. I can't find anything regarding "Task M1454; Delta Journal".

In the link provided in the "Nesbitt-like sum" thread on AoPS, your question is question numbered 1.9.a). The solution uses Cauchy's inequality and is on page 7.

This solution is adapted from Shapiro’s inequality written by A. Khrabrov. It is numbered question 1.9(a).
Construct a sequence $x_{k_i}$ for $i=1,2,...$ by setting $x_{k_1}=\mathrm{max}\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and $x_{k_{i+1}}=\mathrm\{x_{k_i+1},x_{k_i+2}\}$. Note that there exists a smallest $l$ such that $x_{k_l}=x_{k_1}$ and $l\geq\frac{n}{2}$.

 Notice that in the process of constructing the above sequence, the indices $k_1,k_2,...$ strictly increases until we arrive at the smallest $m$ such that $x_{k_m}\in\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2}\}$. Since $x_{k_1}=\mathrm{max}\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, we will eventually get a smallest $l$ such that $x_{k_l}=x_{k_1}$ as the construction continues. As we are only taking at most two steps forward at a time, we have $l\geq\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil\geq\frac{n}{2}$.

We have
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_{k}}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}&\geq\sum_{i=1}^{l-1}\frac{x_{k_i}}{x_{k_i+1}+x_{k_i+2}}\\
&\geq\sum_{i=1}^{l-1}\frac{x_{k_i}}{2x_{k_{i+1}}}\\
&\geq\frac{k}{2}\\
&\geq\frac{n}{4},
\end{align*}$$
where the second-to-last inequality can be obtained using AM-GM or CS.
